# Allow whitespace-nowrap text to overflow to the left (Tailwind CSS)

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am running into an issue with centered text that has the whitespace-nowrap class only overflowing to the right. I want it to still be centered and overflow to the left just as much as the right.

```
<div class="mr-[23px] items-center content-center justify-center">
   <span class="font-inter font-bold text-12px text-white w-[40px] text-center whitespace-nowrap"> 
     testtext
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code can help you, and let me know if you want this result.

```
  <div class="bg-green-400 w-2/4 p-4 flex items-center justify-center overflow-x-scroll scroll-snap-type-x mandatory scroll-snap-align-center">
    <span class="font-inter font-bold text-md text-white w-full text-center whitespace-nowrap"> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A cupiditate 
      distinctio suscipit incidunt itaque id eligendi, sit modi enim soluta libero inventore fugiat deleniti sequi facilis eum ipsum consequuntur ratione!
    </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).